# Setup tools for local development

Tags: python, installation, pip, conda, setuptools

I am trying to develop a package without having to do `pip install .` at each changes of my code. I found using `pip install -e` instead would allow to do that because it would place the package in the actual development path.

What is really strange, is that if I do `pip list` in the root directory of my package, the location would appear to be the right one. However, If I navigate inside the source directory and redo the pip list, the location of the package appears to be the old one in   `miniconda3/envs/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages`... I tried doing a `pip uninstall mypackage` to make sure everything is clean but it doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Actually, it seems like the only directory where `pip list` returns the right path is the directory where I executed `pip install -e .`

Anyone had this problem before ?
Thanks

Comment: by location do u mean  Editable project location ?